# line has a thread breakpoint in app for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm using Xcode and the language I'm using is Swift 3 and I found this problem at the line 39 "Breakpoint"

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var NameTextLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ExplainTextLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var PriceTextLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var FeaturesTextLabel: UILabel!

    let Features = ["Features Include: Siri acts as a musicologist, Advanced searches..., Works with Apple Music, etc", " Feautres Include: Up to 18 Cores, Thunderbolt 3, 5k Display, etc",
        "Feautres Include: AR technology, I messages wont take up storage, A redesinged appstore, etc", "New Faces, Siri Face, Better Pairing Process"]

    let Explain = ["Apple Smart Speaker", "Most Powerfull Mac", "The New OS", "Watch OS4"]

    let Price = ["At $349", "At $4999", "Free", "Free"]

    let Name =  ["Homepod", "iMac Pro", "iOS 11", "Watch OS4"]

    @IBAction func MoreDidTap(sender: AnyObject) {

        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random()) % 4

        let NewName = Name [randomNumber]
        let NewExplain = Explain [randomNumber]
        let NewPrice = Price [randomNumber]
        let NewFeatures = Features [randomNumber]

        NameTextLabel.text = NewName
        ExplainTextLabel.text = NewExplain
        PriceTextLabel.text = NewPrice
        FeaturesTextLabel.text = NewFeatures (This line has a thread breakpoint can anyone help)
    }

}
```

Comment: And you want to remove the breakpoint? Did you search for https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xcode+remove+breakpoint before?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're saying that Xcode is stopping on that line even though you didn't manually set a breakpoint on the line.

My guess is you did not hook up the `FeaturesTextLabel` outlet in your storyboard. Try putting `print(FeaturesTextLabel)` before line 39. What is the output? If it's `nil`, the outlet is not connected.

Comment: Im Sorry Im not really expirienced with Xcode where can I find the Output?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour happens when the app gets crashed due to incorrect binding of UIControls in Xib/Storyboard. Recheck your bindings.